# How to filter variables by its value in a dump file?

Tags: java, jvm, dump, visualvm, jvisualvm

As you see from the picture, I've dumped a binary file from a java process and use VisualVM to analyze it. And I believe there is something wrong with  a key called "rn64832", but I can't filter the ConcurrentHashMap with the problem key and there're too many entries here to do it manually.

Anyone knows how to deal with this situation? Or any solution to check the value on runtime?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [OQL queries](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html)?

Comment: @apangin Yeah. That's exactly what I need. I didn't know it until you remind me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following OQL to find the `ConcurrentHashMap$Node` instance with `key` field equals to `"rn64832"`

```
select node from java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node node where node.key.toString() == "rn64832"
```